# Is there a way to take Alerts in MQL4 expert advisors when using Strategy Tester

Tags: mql4

In my expert advisor inside the `void OnTick()` function I have written `Alert()` function in several places to take important notifications for me. Those are working in normal running mode when the expert advisors are enabled with auto trading on mode and that is not working in using the stratergy tester.

**How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

MetaTrader Terminal 4 documentation is explicit on this, `Alert()` and several other functions are not executed during the MT4-StrategyTester operations.

### Yet, there is a way to get this

If one indeed has such a need, there is a way how to make this happen. The principle is to go a bit wild, `#import` a few DLL-functions beyond the standard MQL4/5 langugage core and make things work together, during a blocking call to an external DLL-imported function.

This way one can have exactly what you have asked for.

### But, never do this in a **`CustomIndicator`** !

This trick will work in MT4-Strategy tester, but since Build 624+, never try to accomplish anything like this in any **`CustomIndicator`**-type of MQL4/5-code. Never.

Designers have chosen to merge a run of all ( yes, you read correctly -- of ALL -- ) `CustomIndicator`-s in one single thread. So if one blocks it, the platform ( as-is 2018/03+ ) stalls and may turn things wreck havoc.

So never try the same trick on any `CustomIndicator`-type of MQL4/5-code. Never.